# netbeans optimize disk usage

Tags: netbeans

Is there some way to optimize the Netbeans IDE for PHP (and Symfony)? It's very good with code hinting, debugging etc, but the downside is that while writing code, the **disk works intensively all the time which is disturbing and besides the editor slows down slightly because of the code hinting**. I have 8GB memory, so it would be quite sufficient for all Netbeans needs. I mean, is it possible to somehow limit the disk usage but without limiting the code hinting? E,g, make it load all code hints to memory.

Comment: yes of course. Use Eclipse! http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: does Eclipse have code hinting for Symfony2 ?

Comment: :$ i am not sure but eclipse has everything and more.

Comment: Here is how I finally dealt with it. I installed RAMDisk with 500MB capacity. Then I moved the .netbeans folder with user files to this RAMDisk (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir). Now it works quietly like a charm.

Comment: Whatever is the solution! Add it as an answer and tick it as the correct answer (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a workaround which solves the problematic symptoms, i.e. the NetBeans editor now works without small delays from code hinting and the disk is quiet. I installed RAMDisk with 500MB capacity. Then I moved the .netbeans folder with user files to this RAMDisk, as described in wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir. Just FYI, moving the project folder itself made no difference, only .netbeans folder was necessary to move.

Comment: +1. This is the more direct link for how to actually move your user dir: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir

Comment: That link mentions: "7.1 permits a --cachedir <path> option to store the IDE's "caches" elsewhere." I just tried it and it seems that just changing the cachedir was sufficient (which you can change permanently in etc/netbeans.conf inside NetBeans's application folder; see my instructions below for how to get to that file on a Mac).

Answer (score 1):

Try to deactivate the Local History plugin, maybe it is causing the high disk usage.
(Be careful if you don't have any vcs)

Although I've never have a problem with Netbeans and disk usage, maybe your disk is broke.

Comment: Deactivating LocalHistory didn't help. The disk is not broken, otherwise it would be broken for all apps not only for NB. When I type in editor "use Symf" there appears a box for code hinting and the title says "Please Wait". The disk works. Only after 1-2 seconds there appears a list of possible code. In other editors (e.g. Eclipse, Visual Studio) code hinting appears immediately and without audible disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to @camcam for answering his own question and posting the RAM disk suggestion. In case there are other Mac users out there who want to do this on a Mac, here are instructions:

1) Create a 500MB RAM disk:

```
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'NetBeansRAMDisk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1048576`
```

2) Locate the NetBeans application in the Finder, control-click on it and select "Show Package Contents"

3) Add this line to Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf:
`netbeans_default_cachedir="/Volumes/NetBeansRAMDisk"`

(Note: the cachedir option was added in NetBeans 7.1.)

For more info, see:

- http://bogner.sh/2012/12/os-x-create-a-ram-disk-the-easy-way/
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir

Answer (score 0):

I have been using NetBeans since version 3.x I have never seen it access the disk all the time. I have regularly ~20 projects open with ~350.000 LOC

You should first make sure it's actually NetBeans that does the disk access (on Windows you can do this with ProcessExplorer, don't know about Linux).

If it's really NetBeans, you could try to give it more memory to cache more data in memory. See the [NetBeans FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSettingHeapSize) for details

And of course make sure your system is not swapping because you have too many programs open (even though it's very unlikely with 8GB RAM but not unseen...).

If you already configured NetBeans to use more memory, maybe you gave it too much and that's why the system is swapping (just a thought).

Is your project stored in Subversion? Do you use TortoiseSVN? With he default installation TortoiseSVN has a background process that caches information about the status of your versioned files. I have seen that scanning the whole harddisk in the background...

Comment: I added a line with "-J-Xmx2560m" to the netbeans.conf and restarted, but no change at all. Well, the issue I am describing does not make it very hard to use NB, it's just uncomfortable because of the disk noise during typing. I have no clue about SVN, I just started Symfony2 and doing a basic tutorial. And it is not another program because there is only Firefox and Explorer.

Comment: Actually, I found that just pressing Enter for a new line in NB causes a first 0,5 second burst of disk usage and then another. So not only code hinting. If I just press Enter in the editor constantly, nothing else, I make my disk work all the time. Maybe NB just works this way, I never used it before

Comment: NetBeans definitely does not work that way. Although I have never used that Symfony2 plugin - maybe it's the plugin that does this disk access.

Comment: I deactivated the "Support for Symfony framework" plugin (http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/6487/47261881.jpg) and restarted but actually nothing changed - there is still code hinting for framework classes. But it's not my point to disable hinting, anyway. I tried to type in a simple text file and css file and the disk was silent. So the issue is only in php.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans for Java development, so that's a difference. You should open an issue in the NetBeans bug tracker. Btw: which version are you using?